# Problem with one-to-many relationship sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I created one-to-many relationship table and according to the sqlite3 documentation I can't insert value into the child table if the referenced table column value in the parent table does not exist.

```
import sqlite3


class Database:

    def __init__(self, database_name):
        self.database_name = database_name

    def create_table(self, table_name, *columns):
        columns = ", ".join(columns)
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        _SQL = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}({columns})"

        cursor.execute(_SQL)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def insert_values(self, table_name, values, *columns):
        dynamic_values = ('?, ' * len(columns))[0:-2]
        columns = ", ".join(columns)
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        _SQL = f"INSERT INTO {table_name}({columns}) VALUES ({dynamic_values})"

        cursor.execute(_SQL, values)

        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def view_values(self, table_name, *columns):
        columns = ", ".join(columns)
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        _SQL = f"SELECT {columns} FROM {table_name}"

        cursor.execute(_SQL)

        the_data = cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        return the_data


data = Database("games.db")
#
# data.create_table("supplier_groups", "group_id integer PRIMARY KEY", "group_name text NOT NULL")
#
data.insert_values("supplier_groups", ("Domestic", ), "group_name")


# data.create_table("suppliers ", "supplier_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY",
#                   "supplier_name TEXT    NOT NULL",
#                   "group_id      INTEGER NOT NULL, "
#                   "FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES supplier_groups (group_id)")

data.insert_values("suppliers", ('ABC Inc.', 9), "supplier_name", "group_id")
```

as you see on this line: `data.insert_values("supplier_groups", ("Domestic", ), "group_name")` - I'm inserting a value into supplier_groups table
and then right here: `data.insert_values("suppliers", ('ABC Inc.', 9), "supplier_name", "group_id")` - I'm inserting value into suppliers table with the group_id that does not exist in the group_suppliers table. Python executes it successfully and adds value to the database, however when attemping to execute this command in SQLITE browser I get this error:
**Execution finished with errors. Result: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed** which is what python should also have done instead of adding it into the database.

So, could anyone explain me what's going on here? Do I understand something in the wrong way? Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From Section 2. Enabling [Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) in the sqlite doc:

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
> `sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`